# Laravel 5 Routes combined

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

Is it possible to combine routes for say news and content? Both are different models and have their own controllers.

```
Link 1 = /news-item/  (news controller & model)    
Link 2 = /about-us/  (content controller & model)
```

As you can see in link 1 and link 2, i want both models to be singular without folders proceeding them.

See below example code that i thought would work, but doesn't:

```
Route::get( '/{page_url}/', 'NewsController@show' );
Route::get( '/{page_url}/', 'ContentController@show' );
```

I have tried this, but it only gets one of the 2 controllers. I can see the obvious conflict.

Is there another way of achieving a single url slug over more than 1 controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see is to define a single route like so:

```
Route::get( '/{page_url}/', 'SlugController@show');
```

Then in the controller method , check whether the slug exists on the news table or content table, then display the relevant content. If nothing is found, show the error.

The other way I see is to use a path in front,

```
Route::get( 'news/{page_url}/', 'NewsController@show');
Route::get( 'content/{page_url}/', 'ContentController@show');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a very bad practice, because the paradigm between request-response uniqueness is lost, in consecuense for future optimization you will have a bad time. There is no way yo achieve what you want if there is no difference in the url:

```
Route::get( '/foo', 'NewsController@show' );
Route::get( '/foo', 'ContentController@show' );
```

As you can see the obvious conflict, how can you note a difference between them in the request? It is not possible. Lavaral will override each route "key" with the same value (url)

Comment: I can see that the way iv done it is bad, but surly there is a way? I'm a newbe at Laravel, bit surprised that such a request can't be accommodated by the amazing flexibility laravel offers. But If it can't, it can't

Comment: this can not be accommodated into lavarel because it is not good practice, it is like "breaking the rules". Laravel is intended to resolve the request for each unique url. The route class works like a HashMap where its structure is based as `'key' => 'value' `, it helps to create even cached map of all of your urls/route for increase the speed of a response.